# Background repeat doesn't seem to work in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, png, internet-explorer-6, background-repeat

I ve applied a background to my page like this,

```
body
{
background:#FFFFFF url('images/color.png') repeat top left;
color:#666666;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:80%;
font-style:normal;
font-variant:normal;
font-weight:normal;
white-space:nowrap;
margin:0 auto;
height:100%;
}
```

This seems to work in IE7,firefox and chrome but certainly not in IE6.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE6 hates pngs..:) leave alone rendering them in background..! you will need some sort of PNGFix for this.. I usually use [this](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/)

Answer (score 0):

ie6 doesnt render pngs well. maybe you should just use a gif or jpg?

Answer (score 0):

why would you use a transparent png for that? Using a gif would be a much better solution