# Non repetition background image (using HTML5, not CSS)?

Tags: html

I want my background image to cover my whole web page but it keeps on repeating. Is there a way to set it to non-repetition via HTML?

Comment: How are you setting the background image in HTML not CSS?

Comment: <body background="images/bg.gif">

Comment: The `background` attribute is deprecated/obsolete in HTML5.

Comment: yes it is not supported in HTML 5 check here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp

Comment: what is your reason not to use CSS? This is exactly what CSS is for!

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

First of all, [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body#attr-background) is an obsolete attribute. Browsers still support it.

Second, it is not part of HTML5, as you can see in the [list of attributes of the body element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element:concept-element-attributes) (see also [global attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes)). *Which also you are not using HTML5, stop pretending you are.*

And finally, there never was an attribute to control how the background repeats. At least not documented.

---

Why do you want this? Even - not so good - old IE6 supports CSS `background-repeat` and `background-size`. Well, except it has problems with PNGs. There are hacks. See [Background repeat doesn't seem to work in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528427/background-repeat-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-ie6) and [IE6 PNG Transparency CSS background-repeat Fix](https://blog.creonfx.com/internet-explorer/ie6-png-transparency-css-background-repeat-fix).

I tried to look how people did this past millelium. You know, around Windows 95. Could not find anything. Perhaps somebody older than me knows, I began learning HTML when we had Windows 98 and IE6. However, I bet the answer is you could not do it.

---

Why don't you use CSS (and HTML5 by the way) for a change?

Comment: @SabaKhan `Why don't you use CSS (and HTML5 by the way) for a change?` I want to know your answer...

Comment: Actually we have to design a pure html based website as our task. That's why!

Comment: @SabaKhan Well, the only idea I have for you is to make the image bigger than the contents of the page. Edit: well, I suppose another alternative is not having a background.

Comment: Yes, Every Display has not same size so you can't be able to get same image output everytime

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inline css (style).

```
<body style="background: url('images/bg.gif');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover">
```

Comment: Err, OP states: "using HTML5 not CSS"

Comment: you can't do it without style

Comment: Exactly. But your answer doesn't say that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background:url(images/bg.gif) center cover / fixed no-repeat">
```

Comment: That is CSS, in an HTML attribute.

Comment: But technically it will be inline css element. Isn't it?

Comment: but it's still CSS