# How can I fit my background image in html without using any css properties?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>hi</title>

</head>

<body background = "prelimbg.png" height="700%" width="1400px">

</body>

</html>
```

This is my code and the bg image keeps repeating when I want it to be fixed and fit in the screen.

Comment: Just because you are new to the community, [Here](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/inline-css) is the help, But please do some research next time on your own and come back if you get stuck even after that.

Comment: without css this is not possible. Why not just using css? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853093/non-repetition-background-image-using-html5-not-css

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Features for assigning background images using plain HTML are very limited and obsolete.

You need CSS for this.